# Javascript/Google Maps causing PIE.htc errors

Tags: javascript, google-maps

All,
I've got the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Store( lat, long, text )
{
    this.latitude = lat;
    this.longitude = long;
    this.html = text;
}

var myStores = [<?php echo $jsData;?>, null];
addLoadEvent(loadMap);
```

This is populated with the following code:

```
$lat = $post->latitude;
$long = $post->longitude;
$post_id = $post->ID;
$get_post_info = get_post($post_id); 
$name = $get_post_info->post_title;
$jsData = $jsData . "new Store( $lat, $long, '$name' ),\n";
```

My page loads fine without the javascript portion. However when I add the javascript I get the following error:

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC LM 8; AskTbAD2/5.14.1.20007)
Timestamp: Wed, 22 Feb 2012 16:45:35 UTC

Message: Arg: Illegal input string in Vector2D
Line: 68
Char: 63
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/parallelus-mingle/assets/css/PIE.htc
```

I actually narrowed it down even further and this line is the one causing the error:

```
addLoadEvent(loadMap);
```

Here is the complete code for the addLoadEvent(loadMap):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script  type="text/javascript">
function addLoadEvent(func) { 
var oldonload = window.onload; 
if (typeof window.onload != 'function'){ 
    window.onload = func
} else { 
    window.onload = function() {
        oldonload();
        func();
    }
}
}

var map,
    infowin=new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:'moin'});
function loadMap() 
{
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map'),
    {   
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center:new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $_SESSION['pav_event_latitude']; ?>, 
                                    <?php echo $_SESSION['pav_event_longitude']; ?>)
    });

  addPoints(myStores);
}

function addPoints( points )
{  
  var bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for ( var p = 0; p < points.length; ++p )
  {
    var pointData = points[p];
    if ( pointData == null ) {map.fitBounds(bounds);return; }
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng( pointData.latitude, pointData.longitude );
    bounds.union(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(point));
    createMarker( point,  pointData.html );
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

}

var number = 2; // or whatever you want to do here
function createMarker(point,  popuphtml) 
{
  var popuphtml = "<div id=\"popup\">" + popuphtml + "<\/div>";
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
      position:point,
      map:map,
      icon:'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld='+number+'|FF776B|000000',
      shadow:'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow'
    }
  );
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowin.setContent(popuphtml)
      infowin.open(map,marker);
    });

}
</script>
```

Any ideas why that would cause an error?

Comment: Is this only happening in IE8? Which version of PIE are you using? Which version of the GoogleMaps API are you using? What other libraries are you using (besides PIE)?

Comment: @pete It works in Firefox, Chrome, Safari etc so just IE8. I'm using Version 1.0 Beta 3 of PIE (at least that is what it says in my file). I'm on Google Maps V3 and I'm using jQuery, Modenizer to name a couple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your `addLoadEvent()` isn't working as it should, and is sending your empty argument list for `loadMap()` to the PIE.htc onload event method. Also, I believe the `typeof` of a function will actually return `object` not `function`. Either way, try dropping this in place of your function:

```
function addLoadEvent(func) { 
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('load', func, false);
    } else if(window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onload', func);
    }
}
```

Another option, which would ensure that it works in all browsers, would be to use jQuery's `$(document).ready()`, [domReady](https://github.com/ded/domready), or some other equivalent.

**Edit:**
Also, this line:

```
var myStores = [<?php echo $jsData;?>, null];
```

will end up with two commas before the `null`, unless you left out some PHP code in your original question.

Comment: Why do you think my var myStroes ending up with two commas before the null? I don't see why you would think that?

Comment: because of this line: 
`$jsData = $jsData . "new Store( $lat, $long, '$name' ),\n";`

Comment: Yes, the $lat, $long and name are are populated with the code box in my question.

Comment: Notice the comma that's getting placed at the end of the string `$jsData`, then look at where you're injecting it with PHP into your inline javascript: `var myStores = [<?php echo $jsData;?>, null];`. It appears there will be two commas, unless you're stripping one out with some code you didn't include in your question. 

Did the alternate `addLoadEvent` method from my answer fix the PIE.htc error?

Comment: I'm not stripping anything out. I'm not sure why any commas would cause an issue. No the addLoadEvent didn't solve the problem. However, I did go out and download the latest PIE.htc file and it doesn't give me an error anymore.

Comment: View source in the browser's rendering, you will see... [new Store( $lat, $long, '$name' ), , null]  as the output.. IE8's JS engine can't handle the empty comma..  you'll see similar issues with [val1, val2,] type array literals as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried downloading the latest version?

See: http://www.hotjoomlatemplates.com/support-forum/643-host/13554-error-showing-on-ie-8

Comment: Never mind... you added your comment before I refreshed the page. Glad that worked for you.